# Two question on ggplot2 R Scatterplots with labels on data

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

**First question.**

I am plotting a scatterplot with ggplot 2 and I would like to add to the datapoint labels, the coordinate of x and y, like this:

```
Second
Viscosity: 2
Time: 60
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar?

**Second question.**

The label position is adjusted with reference of the center. Therefore if I have labels with different size I obtain a differen positioning (line in the following image); is it possible to refer the position (with `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` or similar) from the left side of the label and not the center?

[image]

Below you can find the whole script.

```
Lamination  <- data.frame("Product" = c("First", "second", "Very long word to move 1", "Very long word to move 2", "Third"), "Vix" = c(1.25,2.10,2.99,4.05,5.55), "OT" = c(30,60,90,120,135))
attach(Lamination)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

attach(Lamination)
row.names(Lamination) <- Product

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

nbaplot <- ggplot(Lamination, aes(x= OT, y = Vix)) +   geom_point(color = "red", size = 2) +  ggtitle("Product Range") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + xlab("Time (min)") + ylab("Viscosity")
nbaplot



nbaplot <- nbaplot +   geom_text(
    label=rownames(Lamination), 
    nudge_x = 3.5, nudge_y = 0.0, 
    check_overlap = T
  )
nbaplot
```

Thank you for any eventual reply!!

Comment: You can look into `ggrepel` package for your labelling issues

Comment: Thank you Mohan, I fixed the second issue by using `geom_text_repel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` to combine things you want to display in your text and you can use `ggrepel` package for nicer alignments of text labels

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

Lamination  <- data.frame("Product" = c("First", "second", "Very long word to move 1", "Very long word to move 2", "Third"), "Vix" = c(1.25,2.10,2.99,4.05,5.55), "OT" = c(30,60,90,120,135))

ggplot(Lamination, aes(x= OT, y = Vix)) +   
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 2) +
  ggtitle("Product Range") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlab("Time (min)") + 
  ylab("Viscosity") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = paste0(Product, "\n", "Viscosity:", Vix, "\n", "Time:", OT)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!! You fixed me the problem!! I added only `hjust=0` to justify the text on the left and I defined a smaller size. Thank you again for your help!!